# I started my development server by npm start and then encountered this error anyone could help me fix this Please

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Failed to compile

```
./node_modules/@material-ui/icons/esm/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './ControlPointDuplicateRounded' in 'C:\Users\Archit\Desktop\marketstore-react\node_modules\@material-ui\icons\esm'
```

COULD ANYONE HELP ME WITH THE SOLUTION?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked in the icons of material ui but I didn't find that icon `ControlPointDuplicateRounded` I think this is the reason of that error, try to change that icon with another one from here  https://v4.mui.com/components/material-icons/#material-icons

Comment: Thanks for the reply, okay so basically I have a folder created in node package manager so what do I do with that should I delete that? or should I replace controlpointdup... with another icon???

Comment: Just try to replace the icon with another maybe that will fix your problem

Comment: Okay, Thank You!\

Comment: And to be specific I didn't use any kind of ControlPointDuplicateRounded Icon, also I don't know where exactly it is being used